# Error PLS-00201 identifier must be declared

Tags: plsql

So I keep having this error, and I'm clueless as to what's going on.  I've Googled around, read some questions about this error, and nothing is working.  I just want this to run so I can finish my project.

```
create or replace procedure LOWINVENTORY is

--Variables
ID number;
itemNamed char(15);
description char(20);
startQty number;

--Define inventory item cursor
cursor nextItem is
select inventory.itemID, inventory.itemName, inventory.description, inventory.startQty;
from inventory
where inventory.startQty < 5;

begin
open nextItem;
fetch netxtItem into ID, itemNamed, description, startQty;
if nextItem%notfound then
    dbms_output.put_line('No items in need of reordering.');
else
    dbms_output.put_line('*********************');
    dbms_output.put_line('++Inventory Report++');
    dbms_output.put_line('*********************');
    dbms_output.put_line('Item Name---ID------Description----------Quantity');
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(itemNamed||'-'||ID||'-'||description||'-'||startQty);
        fetch netxtItem into ID, itemNamed, description, startQty;
        if nextItem%notfound then
            dbms_output.put_line('************END REPORT*************');
            exit when nextItem%notfound;
    end loop;
end lowInventory;
```

ERROR:
BEGIN LOWINVENTORY; END;
       *
ERROR at line1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'LOWINVENTORY' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

**EDIT:**

```
INSERT INTO inventory(itemID, itemLocation, itemName, description, typicalPrice, startQty)
VALUES(24548576, 'toolbox1', 'wrench', 'turns bolts', 14.00, 6);
INSERT INTO inventory(itemID, itemLocation, itemName, description, typicalPrice, startQty)
VALUES(83742345, 'toolbox1', 'pliers', 'grabs stuff', 11.00, 4);
INSERT INTO inventory(itemID, itemLocation, itemName, description, typicalPrice, startQty)
VALUES(39287426, 'chest2', 'jigsaw', 'cuts stuff', 28.00, 3);
INSERT INTO inventory(itemID, itemLocation, itemName, description, typicalPrice, startQty)
VALUES(48927349, 'chest1', 'blowtorch', 'torches stuff', 330.00, 2);
INSERT INTO inventory(itemID, itemLocation, itemName, description, typicalPrice, startQty)
VALUES(85463455, 'bench3', 'oil filter', 'filters stuff', 16.00, 20);
```

TABLE CREATION:

```
create table inventory
    (
        itemID number(8) not null primary key constraint lengthCHK8 check(length(itemID)=8),
        itemLocation varchar2(10), 
        itemName varchar2(12) not null,
        description varchar2(20),
        typicalPrice decimal(7,2) not null constraint notNeg2 check(typicalPrice >=0),
        startQty number(4) not null constraint notNeg5 check(startQty >=0)
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is filled with silly mistakes, 
firstly ,

```
select inventory.itemID, inventory.itemName, 
inventory.description, inventory.startQty;   --> semicolan here, the statment doesnt end
from inventory
where inventory.startQty < 5;
```

Second,

```
cursor nextItem is --> using nextItem as name in cursor but "netxtItem" while opening it,  a typo
```

Third,

No end if inside the else part,loop

Here is the procedure that has been compiled,
I created the inventory table with just 4 columns used in procedure to compile the procedure

```
SQL> create or replace procedure LOWINVENTORY is
  2
  3  --Variables
  4  ID number;
  5  itemNamed char(15);
  6  description char(20);
  7  startQty number;
  8
  9  --Define inventory item cursor
 10  cursor nextItem is
 11  select inventory.itemID, inventory.itemName, inventory.description, inventory.startQty
 12  from inventory
 13  where inventory.startQty < 5;
 14
 15  begin
 16  open nextItem;
 17  fetch nextItem into ID, itemNamed, description, startQty;
 18  if nextItem%notfound then
 19      dbms_output.put_line('No items in need of reordering.');
 20  else
 21      dbms_output.put_line('*********************');
 22      dbms_output.put_line('++Inventory Report++');
 23      dbms_output.put_line('*********************');
 24      dbms_output.put_line('Item Name---ID------Description----------Quantity');
 25      loop
 26          dbms_output.put_line(itemNamed||'-'||ID||'-'||description||'-'||startQty);
 27          fetch nextItem into ID, itemNamed, description, startQty;
 28          if nextItem%notfound then
 29              dbms_output.put_line('************END REPORT*************');
 30              exit when nextItem%notfound;
 31             end if;
 32             end loop;
 33  end if;
 34
 35  end lowInventory;
 36  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

**EDIT**

```
SQL> insert into inventory (itemid,itemname,description,startqty) values (1,'abc','descp1',1) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into inventory (itemid,itemname,description,startqty) values (2,'abcd','descp2',1) ;

1 row created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;


SQL> exec lowInventory;
*********************
++Inventory Report++
*********************
Item Name---ID------Description----------Quantity
abc            -1-descp1              -1
abcd           -2-descp2              -1
************END REPORT*************

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**EDIT 2**

with the data you have provided

```
SQL> exec lowinventory;
*********************
++Inventory Report++
*********************
Item Name---ID------Description----------Quantity

jigsaw         -39287426-cuts stuff          -3
pliers         -83742345-grabs stuff         -4
jigsaw         -39287426-cuts stuff          -3
blowtorch      -48927349-torches stuff       -2
************END REPORT*************

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much.  I'd buy you a beer if I could.  Something strange must be going on with my Oracle account then.  I made the corrections and I'm getting the same error.  I'm using the command "exec LOWINVENTORY" and trying "exec lowInventory" and they're both coming up with the same error as above.

Comment: Can you please post the table structure and sample data so I can simulate?

Comment: I have inserted sample data, and ran the procedure, see the edit section for the ouptut