# PLS-00201: identifier must be declared in Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a PL/SQL Procedure code, which runs when it is `/` , but doesn't runs when it's executed. The error message I get is

```
SQL> EXECUTE MAXINUM;
BEGIN MAXINUM; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'MAXINUM' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The code which I'm working on is  :

```
DECLARE
    N NUMBER;
    M NUMBER;
    O NUMBER;
    P NUMBER;
    X NUMBER;
PROCEDURE MAXINUM(N IN NUMBER, M IN NUMBER, O IN NUMBER, P IN NUMBER, X OUT NUMBER) IS
    BEGIN
    IF N>M AND N>O AND N>P THEN
        X:=N;
    ELSIF M>N AND M>O AND M>P THEN
        X:=M;
    ELSIF O>N AND O>M AND O>P THEN
        X:=O;
    ELSIF P>N AND P>M AND P>O  THEN
        X:=P;
    END IF;
    END;

BEGIN
    N:=&NUMBER;    
    M:=&NUMBER;
    O:=&NUMBER;
    P:=&NUMBER;
    MAXINUM(N,M,O,P,X);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HIGHEST NUMBER = '||X);
END;
/
```

When it gave the 'identifier error', I tried dropping this procedure I got the error:

```
SQL> DROP PROCEDURE MAXINUM;
DROP PROCEDURE MAXINUM
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04043: object MAXINUM does not exist
```

I have so far read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957063/error-pls-00201-identifier-must-be-declared), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733197/oracle-pls-00201-identifier-vat-register-ap-vat-reg3-must-be-declared), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718779/pls-00201-identifier-r-cur-must-be-declared-in-dynamic-sql) solutions and other solutions some what related to this error.

Comment: For the record, this is a half-cooked implementation of [the Oracle built-in function `greatest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions078.htm#SQLRF00645)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written an anonymous block with a local procedure `MAXINUM()`. This procedure can be called within that block but does not exist outside that block. Consequently you cannot call it independently.

If you want to use the procedure elsewhere you need to create it as a first class database object:

```
create or replace procedure MAXINUM
   (N IN NUMBER, M IN NUMBER, O IN NUMBER, P IN NUMBER, X OUT NUMBER)
is 
BEGIN
    IF N>M AND N>O AND N>P THEN
        X:=N;
    ELSIF M>N AND M>O AND M>P THEN
        X:=M;
    ELSIF O>N AND O>M AND O>P THEN
        X:=O;
    ELSIF P>N AND P>M AND P>O  THEN
        X:=P;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Now you can call it in your code, like this:

```
DECLARE
    N NUMBER;
    M NUMBER;
    O NUMBER;
    P NUMBER;
    X NUMBER;
BEGIN
    N:=&NUMBER;    
    M:=&NUMBER;
    O:=&NUMBER;
    P:=&NUMBER;
    MAXINUM(N,M,O,P,X);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HIGHEST NUMBER = '||X);
END;
/
```

Points to note:

1. what happens if a parameter is null?
2. what happens if two arguments have the same value?
3. the convention would be to declare this as a function and return the highest value instead of setting an OUT parameter.

---

Incidentally I assume you're doing this as an exercise, as it is a re-implementation of [an existing Oracle built-in function, `greatest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions078.htm#SQLRF00645).

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this an exercise, your answer makes sense in theory but when I try to apply `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAXINUM(N IN NUMBER, M IN NUMBER, O IN NUMBER, P IN NUMBER, X OUT NUMBER) AS` I get an error stating `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
exists prior` Perhaps a descriptive answer might help me?

Comment: I think you're still trying to define the procedure inside the anonymous block. You need to create it first, in a separate standalone piece of DDL. I have expanded my answer to clarify this.